# Send reference of a class throw a method

Tags: c#

I define a class and a TryParse method. When I write TryParse like below the result is always null and TryParse result has MyProperty=0:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public static MyClass Parse(string s)
    {
        MyClass outC=new MyClass();
        outC.MyProperty=int.Parse(s);
        return outC;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string s,MyClass result)
    {
        try
        {
            result = Parse(s);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
 }
```

But if I write method like this the result is true.

```
class MyClass
 {
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public static MyClass Parse(string s)
    {
        MyClass outC=new MyClass();
        outC.MyProperty=int.Parse(s);
        return outC;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string s,out MyClass result)
    {
        try
        {
            result = Parse(s);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why a reference type need out keyword?

Comment: Your second example doesn't compile : `use of unassigned out parameter`

Comment: Also, I can't see where you're calling either method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `try-catch` for normal workflow:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, MyClass result)
{
    if(result == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("result");
    int prop;
    bool success = int.TryParse(s, out prop);
    if(success)
        result.Prop = prop;
    return success;
}
```

If you want that the method initializes and returns the instance of `MyClass`, use `out`:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, out MyClass result)
{
    result = new MyClass();
    int prop;
    bool success = int.TryParse(s, out prop);
    if(success)
        result.Prop = prop;
    return success;
}
```

Use  it in this way:

```
MyClass c;
bool b = TryParse("10", out c);
// c is initialized
```

or use the `ref` keyword to pass by reference:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, ref MyClass result)
{
    if(result == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("result");
    int prop;
    bool success = int.TryParse(s, out prop);
    if (success)
        result.Prop = prop;
    return success;
}
```

Use it in this way:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(); // must be initialized
bool b = TryParse("10", ref c);
```

If an argument is passed with `ref` you can  modify the original instance, so it's even possible to assign `null`. If you don't make it `ref` you could also assign `null` (or a different instance of `MyClass`) but you would only modify the copy of the reference instead of the original.

So this would make make `c` `null` in the calling method:

```
public static void MakeNull(ref MyClass result)
{
    result = null;
}

MyClass c = new MyClass();
MakeNull(ref c);
Console.Write(c == null); // true
```

whereas this would not modify it:

```
public static void MakeNull(MyClass result)
{
    result = null;
}

MyClass c = new MyClass();
MakeNull(c);
Console.Write(c == null); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

[`out` is a keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) that when used in a method parameter means that you have to assign a value to the variable before returning.

So in your method, you have to assign `result`

```
result = new MyClass();
```

Before returning. The parameter doesn't have to be set before calling the method. And you should return a `bool`.

The method return value will be a `bool` and the parameter you sent as `out` will have the value assigned in the method.

Example

```
MyClass result;
bool success = TryParse("abc", out result);
// result here will have what the method assigned
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in my computer.

```
    class MyClass2
    {
        public int Prop { get; set; }

        public static bool TryParse(string s, MyClass2 result)
        {
            try
            {
                result.Prop = int.Parse(s);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    private static void TestMethod(string str)
    {
        var obj = new MyClass2();
        var rst = MyClass2.TryParse(str, obj);
        Console.WriteLine("bool:{0},int:{1}",rst,obj.Prop);
    }

    [Fact]
    private void TestCase()
    {
        TestMethod("445");
        TestMethod("abc");
    }
    //out put       
bool:True,int:445       
bool:False,int:0
```

You are correct,for reference parameters ,there is no need for the out keyword.
How did you use your TryParse mehtod?

Comment: Show your call statements.